# split a column includes key:=value into multiple columns in python

Tags: python

I have many csv files with "|" delimiter which one column includes key and value (but not json). I need to read all those csv file, split that column into multiple columns (as key as the column name and the given value) and save output in one big csv file.

one of the csv file is like:

```
id   | name|message
12478|  A  |{img_type:=png,key_id:=f235, client_status:=active, request_status:=open}
12598|  B  |{img_type:=none,address_id:=c156, client_status:=active, request_status:=closed}
```

output will be:

```
id   |name| Img_type|Key_id|address_id|Client_status|Request_status
12478|  A | png     |f235  |NULL      |active       | open
12598|  B | none    |NULL  |c156      |active       | closed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize pandas for your problem

```py
import pandas as pd

def split_to_dict(row):
    row_splitted = row[1:-1].split(',')
    return dict(
        [
            i.strip().split(':=') for i in row_splitted
        ]
    )

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', delimiter="|")
new_df = df.message.apply(split_to_dict).apply(pandas.Series)

final = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)
final = final.drop(columns=['message'])
final.to_csv('your_splitted_file.csv', sep="|", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works fine when all rows have same key:=value! But I do have some other rows which sometimes one of the key:=value is missing. In that case it gives me error "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1;2 is required". any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide example of those rows so I can recreate the error?
I tried it with your example input where second row doesn't have `key_id` but it worked fine.

Comment: I have checked my log file (very big file) and it seems the problem is: some lines are broken, for example in one line I have: **client_status:=active12598|  C  |{img_type:=none,address_id:=c198, client_status:=active, request_status:=open}**. So basically next line mixed with previous row. Now I have to find a way to ignore those lines before trying to split them.